# Ned Block on the Psychology of the Homunculi-Head

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, psychology

In his ‘Troubles with Functionalism’, Block develops his now-famous Homunculi-Head thought experiment. At one point (p.292), he claims that there are psychological differences between a person and their Homunculi-Headed simulation, but I don’t get what psychological differences Block has in mind. To develop this question, let me first summarise Block’s thought experiment.

According to (one version of) functionalism, there is a Turing machine T that I realise. Imagine a being, Blocky, that also realises T, but in a radically different way: Blocky’s body is an exact duplicate of mine; but instead of the brain, there is a control centre, in which little men perform certain, simple tasks. Collectively, they make sure that Blocky realises T: if Blocky is in state *s* and receives input *i*; and if T’s table requires output *o* and transition into state *s+*; then there’s a little man who sets *o* in motion and makes the transition to *s+* happen. (*o* could be a wince, while ‘the transition to *s+*’ means letting the others know the system in now in *s+*.)
Although Blocky is a functional duplicate of me, he isn’t a mental duplicate (says Bock): when Blocky and I have our fingers pricked, we both wince; but only I experience pain. Blocky experiences nothing: he has no qualia, and there’s nothing it is like to be Blocky.
Conclusion: if being functionally identical doesn’t entail being mentally identical, then mental states (esp. qualia) couldn’t be functional states.

I get the argument, and I also get (and share) the intuition that Blocky doesn’t experience any qualia. Later in the paper, however, Block makes the claim I don’t get:

Homunculi-Heads like Blocky “are not things to which neurophysiological theories true of us apply, and *if they are construed as Functional* (rather than Psychofunctional) simulations, they need not be things to which psychological (information-processing) theories true of us apply.” (p.292, italics in original)

Neurophysiological theories that are true of us don’t apply to Blocky, because such theories describe what’s happening in our brains. Since Blocky doesn’t have a brain, these theories are false of Blocky. At first, I thought that psychological theories that are true of us don’t apply to Blocky because of statements like (A).

(A) He winced in response to the electric shock *because the shock hurt him*.

This is true of me (let’s say) but false of Blocky, because it refers to a quale (the shock *hurt*), which is absent in Blocky. Yet (A) can’t be what Block has in mind: the fact that different psychological theories apply to Blocky and me is supposed to **support** the intuition that Blocky doesn’t have any qualia. So, we can’t rely on the absence of qualia to show that Blocky and I are psychologically different.
Block seems to think that there’s a difference there, only if we consider folk-psychological theories. (That’s what ‘construed as Functional rather than Psychofunctional’ is about.) At the same time, he keeps putting ‘information-processing’ after ‘psychological’ – which sounds more like scientific, cognitive psychology.

So, my question is: what (folk-)psychological differences does Block see between me and my Homunculi-Headed simulation?

Comment: A scan of this paper showed he does follow somewhat Dennet’s ‘string of consciousness’ (which is based on Cartesian duality) he calls ‘Cartesian Theater’. An observant station functioning (much like a homunculi) as a narrative reporter of the world we are immersed into. 
There are relativity issues in any homunculi and multi mind theory of consciousness. Dennet is looking at function based on Decartes’ methodology and Block is proposing functionalism as some form of alchemy, with a host of possible psychological data points correlating to the mind as a predicate for action. You have choices

Comment: The mistake Block seems to make is to assume that Blocky will wince. Why would he do this if he has no qualia? The idea appears to be absurd. It would be easier to say that because Blocky does not wince we can assume he has no qualia. If we say Blocky will wince despite not feeling the pain then we have muddled the issues beyond recovery. How would we explain this wincing?

Comment: Wouldn’t we explain the wince simply through the functional equivalence? That’s the output the system gives when receiving a prick in the finger as input. Even a zombie (who is behaviourally equivalent to us by definition) will wince, although she has no qualia.

Comment: @Mark Oxford: Have you come across [this](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/1971/12/30/the-case-against-bf-skinner/) essay by Chomsky, *The Case against B.F. Skinner*? You might find it intresting reading - it was a comprehensive debunking of the whole notion of behaviourlism.

Comment: Here's a tasty little titbit from it:"As to its social implications, Skinner’s science of human behavior, being quite vacuous, is as congenial to the libertarian as to the fascist...there is little doubt that a theory of human malleability might be put to the service of totalitarian doctrine."

Comment: And heres something else that might delight you from the same essay, this times the quote is from B.F.Skinner himself - we should be so priviliged: “It is in the nature of an experimental analysis of human behavior that it should strip away the functions previously assigned to autonomous man and transfer them one by one to the controlling environment”

Answer (score 2):

### Introduction

In 'Troubles with Functionalism', Block introduces functionalism as a "new incarnation of behaviorism" where "sensory inputs and mental states" produce a "disposition to act and have certain mental states" (262).  The functionalist seeks an ontological *reduction* of *mental states* to *functional states* viz. *functional descriptions* of their *logical relations* grounded<sup>1</sup> in *physical* (sensory) inputs and (e.g. behavioral) outputs.  Such functional states could be modeled in terms of logical sentences like *Ramsey functional correlates*, or as parts of dynamic (state) models or computational systems like *Turing machines*.  An *actual* machine (or nonmachine) which *implements* such states, sensory inputs and behaviors (outputs) can be said to *realize*<sup>2</sup> the corresponding model.

Block distinguishes two methods of reduction: *Functionalism*, where inputs, outputs and states correspond to *common-sense* or *folk*-psychological theory, and *Psychofunctionalism* where inputs, outputs and states correspond to *scientific* psychological theory (allowing e.g. neural activations as an input or output) (268-9).  The quote on p. 292 occurs in a context where Block has just contrasted two types of homunculi: one composed of subatomic aliens *scientifically indistinguishable* from an ordinary human (realizing a *Psychofunctional* model of brain activity), and one whose inner workings (perhaps fleas, tiny men, or a Turing machine) are empirically completely unlike an ordinary human (Blocky, realizing a *Functional* model of human behavior).  Here we can regard the *Functional* simulation as one that fulfills a reduction of *folk*-psychological states and behaviors, and the *Psychofunctional* simulation as one that fulfills a reduction of *neurological* states and interactions.

### Troubles with Blocky

Block implies that a *Functionalist* should accept *ex hypothesi* that Blocky has Functional states and therefore (*folk*-psychological) *mental states* identical to a human.  However, there is room for disagreement.  As a simple example, if Blocky were constructed to simulate person A, A may know themselves to have a genuine psychology including a genuine *quale* for pain.  However, they may have reasonable doubt as to whether Blocky has the same quale or even any qualia at all.  If we follow a Kripkean notion of identity we can then trivially conclude that it's *not necessary* that Blocky has the same mental state.

In another instance, Block gives an example of an *intermittent paralytic* on page 297.  Consider a different (not Block's) intermittent paralytic *Mitty* with a *neurological* condition which often prevents him from *drinking water* or realizing that he is incapable of doing so.  Mitty in one instance *desires* to drink a glass of water and *believes* himself capable of doing so.  But a paradigmatic Functional interpretation of believing oneself capable of *drinking water* and desiring to *drink water* may be to *typically* result in *drinking water*.  However, if Mitty typically fails to *drink water*, a corresponding Blocky under that paradigmatic Functional interpretation would not be ascribed the functional state of both believing oneself capable of *drinking water* and *desiring to drink water*.  Arguably, this corresponds to a difference in *information-processing* between Mitty and Blocky<sup>3</sup>.

Shoemaker suggests for the case of paralytics etc., considering a "paradigmatically embodied person," which Block claims to be a retreat from Functionalism to Psychofunctionalism (298-9).  It seems we can infer that Block would say that in terms of *information-processing*, a *Functional* Blocky is not necessarily the same as the corresponding human (Mitty).  The case is different for *information processing* in the context of a *Psychofunctional* homunculus, not based on *folk*-psychology.  There we might exchange the terms of *belief* and *desire* for *empirical* expressions in an appropriate *scientific* psychological theory.  Following Block, it seems plausible to accept *ex hypothesi* that such a simulation would *necessarily* have the same empirical psychology (*information-processing*) as a human.

### Mental Differences and the Argument against Functionalism

The quote from p. 292 seems to suggest a coherent argument against Functionalism.  In the first part, things like Blocky "are not things to which neurophysiological theories true of us apply."  Most relevant here is that if humans are A, and Blocky B, that *from a neurophysiological perspective* A and B are completely different. So, if you think that *neurophysiology* is relevant to mental properties, you should expect that *from a mental perspective* A does not equal B.

"They need not be things to which psychological (information-processing) theories true of us apply," appears to be a *modal* claim. We can express this as saying that from an *information-processing* perspective it is *not necessary* that B is equivalent to A.

Here, we can simplify and formalize the argument to show how one would argue for mental differences and how to use those differences to argue against Functionalism. For convenience, we'll refer to the following contexts: neurophysiologically (N), information-processing (I), qualia (Q), mentally (M), and functionally (F). We'll also include a human A, and Blocky B and use modal logic operators `[]` and `<>` for necessary and possible respectively.

`Given a _Functional_ Blocky, we obtain some simplified statements from the quote:
 1. (N) A =/= B
 2. (I) ~[] (B = A)
And transform them a bit
 2a. (I) <> ~(A = B)
Since properties of A are fixed
 2b. <> Exists B s.t. (I) ~(A = B)
 2c. <> Exists B s.t. (I) (A =/= B) 
But if we take such a B to be theoretically plausible, and as the B under consideration then
 2d. (I) (A =/= B)
So we have
 3. (N, I) (A =/= B)
Meaning that neurophysiologically, and from an information-processing standpoint, humans are not equivalent to Blocky.  Block elsewhere supports the intuition that there's a corresponding absence of or difference in qualia.
 *3a. (Q) (A =/= B) or (B has no qualia)
Although it doesn't necessarily follow, Block thinks it's reasonable that we have intuitions that Q, N and I are relevant to mental state.  If so, perhaps we can conclude:
 *3b. (M) (A =/= B)`

Alternatively, *3a as (B has no qualia) can satisfy the premise AQ of the *Absent Qualia Argument* (*AQA*)

`From _intuition_, _prima facie_
 AQ. (<> Exists B, B has no qualia)
But since (presumably) mentality requires qualia
 *3b. (M) (A =/= B)`

With *3b we can make the argument against Functionalism:

`We introduced Blocky as Functionally equivalent to A
 4. (F) A = B
But if we want to use functionalism as a reductive theory of mind, then we'd expect mental equivalence to be implied by functional equivalence.  We'd say that 
 *5. for all X, Y (F) X = Y -> (M) X = Y **or** for all X, Y (F) X = Y <-> (M) X = Y
so for A and B we can say
 5b. (F) A = B -> (M) A = B
But if we believe *3b, then
 6. (F) A = B and (M) A =/= B
So if *3b is reasonable, we should deny *5.`

Block's distinction between Functional and Psychofunctional simulations alongside his phrasing of "psychological (information-processing) theories" appears to emphasize e.g. neuroscientific theories of how we process information.  This seems to correspond to how Blocky's internal logic is not the same as the logic realized inside a human brain.

In response, a functionalist (perhaps Psychofunctionalist) like Shoemaker would accept the *AQA* but deny *3a and so deny *3b.  An *eliminativist* could accept AQ and *3a but deny that *3b follows.  Block seems to think AQ, *3a and *3b are all reasonable.

---

<sup>1</sup> See symbol grounding problem.  Block describes this as "'tacking down' mental states only at the periphery." (284)

<sup>2</sup> *Realization* is a standard term for an implementation of a computational model (e.g. a Turing machine) or other input/output system in mathematical or computational logic.  See also [Realization (systems)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_(systems)), and p. 306 for an example for Block's use regarding nonmachines.

<sup>3</sup> To expand a bit on this, one common *folk*-psychological theory that seems suitable for a Functional law relates belief, desire and action.  We might say the *desire* to φ along with the *belief* that one can φ, *typically* results in doing φ.  So a paradigmatic Functional interpretation of *belief* and *desire* would be *belief* that can φ + *desire* to φ -> *typically* does φ.  We'll call this Functional law belief+desire->action.  Since Blocky is a simulation of Mitty, Blocky *typically* fails to *drink water*.  Yet since Blocky is a *Functional* simulation he follows Functional laws and has corresponding mental states.  But because of belief+desire->action, Blocky to be a Functional simulation must lack either the *desire* to drink water, or the *belief* that he is capable of *drinking water*.  If Mitty doesn't drink because he can't while Blocky doesn't drink because he either doesn't desire to or doesn't believe that he can, this seems to correspond to a difference in *information-processing* between Mitty and Blocky.

This further seems to suggest a difference in mental states between Mitty and Blocky.  A Functionalist could respond that Mitty doesn't actually have belief+desire for drinking water.  But that seems to disagree with common-sense psychology.  Alternatively, one could deny belief+desire->action.  But we are left with a similar problem for any mental state that can't be expressed in a paradigmatic Functional way.

Comment: Thanks! You suggest that the quote “isn’t intended to show that Blocky doesn’t have qualia”, but I’m not sure. Block wants to back the intuition that Blocky has no qualia, and he seems to think that (possible) psychological differences are the way to do it: “since [Blocky] need not be anything like you psychologically […] it is reasonable to doubt that it has mentality”. (296) “there is good reason to take seriously our intuition that [Blocky has] no mentality. The good reason is that […he] need not have […] psychological (information-processing) […] mechanisms anything like ours”. (301)

Comment: I appreciate this is a modal claim/argument: Block says ‘need not have’ the same psychology, rather than ‘doesn’t have’. I’d still like to understand how Blocky’s psychology *could* differ from mine. In other words, I’d like to know more about the second premise in your argument: if the (P, I)-standpoint accepts ~[] (B = A), that standpoint presumably acknowledges a situation/world where A and B in fact differ. I’d like to know what that situation looks like (according to (P, I)).

Comment: @Mark Block certainly wants to back the intuition that Blocky has no qualia, but he makes that argument elsewhere.  I think you are confusing _mentality_ (mental states) for qualia (phenomenal experience).  In my breakdown, psychological (P) differences like differences in qualia are a _premise_ for this portion of argument.  The hopeful conclusion establishing mental (M) differences *3b, is what Block would be supporting on 296, and 301.  If we take (I) to be differences in e.g. belief and desire, Blocky w/ trained fleas we expect to satisfy (P, I) A =/= B (differing qualia, belief, desire).

Comment: If “differences in qualia are a premise for this portion of argument”, isn’t the argument trivial? If Blocky lacks qualia, *of course* he and I are different mentally (but functionally the same) – simply because qualia are a kind of mental state. (Perhaps you don’t think they are?) Won’t the Functionalist try to reject the premise that there are “differences in qualia” between Blocky and me? It seems to me that that’s the claim Block needs to (and is trying to) support. Once we grant there are “differences in qualia”, the conclusion that there are mental differences seems far less contentious.

Comment: @Mark Block supports the _prima facie_ argument from _intuition_ that (<> Exists B, B doesn't have qualia) and so *3b (AQA).  He continues this, e.g. by claiming that (I) ~[] (A = B) supports the intuition.  But _the given quote_ presents an argument roughly following the more formal structure I gave (excluding (P)sychologically).  Functionalists (except _eliminativists_) are likely to deny absence (and maybe difference) in qualia; per Shoemaker (cf. _Functionalism and Qualia_) absent _or_ differing qualia are sufficient for *3b, but Block I think is rightly unconvinced regarding the latter.

Comment: Actually, maybe I skimmed over this a little too quickly.  I'll see if I can update my answer to better respect your interpretation and Block's terminology.

Comment: “He continues this, e.g. by claiming that (I) ~[] (A = B) supports the intuition.” I’ll wait for your update, but I *think* that’s what I was trying to get at: we have the intuition that (<> Exists B, B doesn't have qualia) – that Blocky needn’t have qualia – and support this intuition by noting possible psychological and information-processing differences between him and me. My question, again, was what these possible psychological and info-processing differences are. Part of what mystifies me is that he says there are *folk*-psychological differences, but not *scientific* psychological ones.

Comment: Updated now, although my interpretation suggests that Functional simulations realize a reduction of _folk_-psychological differences while Psychofunctional simulations realize a reduction of _scientific_ (e.g. neurological) psychological differences.  According to that it seems that the "psychological (information processing) theories" would consider the full complexity of logic realized by neural activity within the brain.  Such would not be simulated for Blocky w/ fleas, but would be for person composed of subatomic aliens.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I’m not sure I understand the phrase “Functional simulations realize a reduction of folk-psychological differences”: what do you mean, they *realise* a reduction? A reduction to what? Also, I’d still be curious to hear a *concrete example* of a folk-psychological law that’s true of me but not (necessarily) true of Blocky.

Comment: A Turing machine defines an abstract model of a computation device.  The actual machine which performs the computations is said to _realize_ that model.  Similarly for other devices which implement a given mathematical logic. 
Functionalism is often considered as a follow-on to behaviorism or physicalism.  In that context, it's an ontological reduction by eliminating the need for dualist mental states.  I've updated to try to clarify and give an example of a folk-psychological difference (for Blocky, belief+desire are _defined_ in terms of producing a typical result, but shouldn't apply to A)

Comment: I still find ‘realise a reduction’ a bit odd: physical devices realise machine tables, philosophers make reductive claims–but I’m nitpicking! I don’t get Mitty. Is the folk-law: ‘The desire to φ is that mental state which, in the presence of a belief that there’s an opportunity to φ, will result in φ-ing’? This is false of Mitty, but why is it true of Blocky? As a paralytic’s simulation, he never φs, either. I.e., he also doesn’t have a state that, when combined with the belief that there’s an opportunity to φ, results in φ-ing. (Btw didn’t we want a law that’s F of Blocky and T of the human?)

Comment: "Realize a reduction of folk-psychological states etc." was to mean that the simulation realizes a functional (e.g. state table) interpretation (i.e. reduction) of folk-psychological states (also see 306).  Blocky is designed so any _Functional_ law will be T of him - here maybe he lacks the belief/desire to drink.  But Mitty presumably shows the Functional law to be false.  A Functionalist can deny the folk-law or deny Mitty the belief/desire, but either way seems to disagree with folk-psychology.  (Shoemaker provides a different interpretation, but Block would call that Psychofunctionalism)